# Can minio be run as nonroot user in a docker container?

Tags: dockerfile, minio

Can someone let me know if we can run MINIO as non root user?
Found some articles where it can run only as root and not as non root.
Please guide if someone has any idea on how it can achieved if possible.

Answer (score 1):

From [Minio docs (Run MinIO Docker as a regular user)](https://docs.min.io/docs/minio-docker-quickstart-guide), you can provide the `--user` argument to the `docker run` command.

An example for Linux/macOS, from the doc:

```sh
mkdir -p ${HOME}/data
docker run -p 9000:9000 \
  --user $(id -u):$(id -g) \
  --name minio1 \
  -e "MINIO_ROOT_USER=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE" \
  -e "MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD=wJalrXUtnFEMIK7MDENGbPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY" \
  -v ${HOME}/data:/data \
  minio/minio server /data
```